# What's the actual meaning behind かつて生きた最後の夏/最初で最後の一日だ and how to translate it?

Tags: grammar, translation

This is my first ever question to this site and I'm still a beginner in Japanese, so forgive me if there's any mistakes:

So, I have been trying to translate this comic as a sort of practice for learning Japanese using Jisho and Deepl machine translation, and the two things that have been giving me the most are the ones mentioned in the question's title.

I have tried translating かつて生きた最後の夏 as [The last ever lively Summer] or [And the last Summer that I ever lived] which Deepl conjured up with something similar, but I still have a nagging feeling that's wrong.

As for 最初で最後の一日だ, I translated it as [The one and only time/chance I had, this day.]

The の一日 was what giving me the most trouble with that particular sentence, and I tried to compromise with my translation.

Again, I'm still an absolute beginner regarding Japanese so forgive me if there was any mistakes. What's the correct way of translating those two particular sentences?

Comment: Is the story about a dead person?

Comment: Echoing @aguijonazo 's question, this sounds like something told/narrated from the perspective of someone who's died.  Without any more context, 最初で最後の一日だ sounds a bit like, "It was the first time for my last day" almost as if this is something he repeats time and time again.  Perhaps you could provide a bit more background and context.

Answer (score 0):

This is my version of translation.

かつて生きた最後の夏
the last summer that I ever lived

最初で最後の一日だ
The first yet last day
or
My first yet last day

By the way, I want to share two tips with you.

1. If you give some context more than just one phrase, the translation will be more accurate.
2. You can use modern AI tools like ChatGPT or Bing Chat (they are internally the same thing) to give you better learning experience. Try to give AI the prompt like "Please translate this sentence into English and explain it in grammar." and you can learn much about it.